# Как сохранить введенные пользователем данные в поле ACF в Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, acf

Есть сайт на Wordpress, установлен плагин Advanced Custom Fields.

Дополнительные поля используются для ввода данных зарегистрированных пользователей. Изначально эти данные введены в админке. Нужно на сайте на странице пользователя сделать эти поля редактируемыми и возможность перезаписать данные.

Нашел пример подобного решения, но данные не сохраняются:

```
function my_acf_user_form_func( $atts ) {

  $a = shortcode_atts( array(
    'field_group' => ''
  ), $atts );

  $uid = get_current_user_id();

  if ( ! empty ( $a['field_group'] ) && ! empty ( $uid ) ) {
    $options = array(
      'post_id' => 'user_'.$uid,
      'field_groups' => array( intval( $a['field_group'] ) ),
      'return' => add_query_arg( 'updated', 'true', get_permalink() )
    );

    ob_start();

    acf_form( $options );
    $form = ob_get_contents();

    ob_end_clean();
  }

    return $form;
}

add_shortcode( 'my_acf_user_form', 'my_acf_user_form_func' );

//adding AFC form head
function add_acf_form_head(){
    global $post;

  if ( !empty($post) && has_shortcode( $post->post_content, 'my_acf_user_form' ) ) {
        acf_form_head();
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'add_acf_form_head', 7 );
```

Может кто сталкивался с подобными задачами...

Comment: Нужно обновить или добавить данные в ACF поле делайте это так: 
 update_field( 'acf key', 'value', $post_id );

Comment: Даниил, может есть пример использования функции update_field(), в документации ACF не очень понятно написано?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да есть. Просто создайте в корне `WP` файл `test.php` и напишите в нем:

```
<?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); require("wp-blog-header.php"); ?>

<?php update_field("field_5a71973d375fa","Value update", "user_2378"); ?>
```

- Ключь поля, можно узнать в админки.
- Значение.
- ID поста.

---

Результат в админ-панели:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Почему то не работает. Делаю так: <?php $author_id = wp_get_current_user()->ID; update_field('field_5a9fd1dc3d58c', '10000', $author_id); ?>

Comment: ID верный, рядом выводятся те же поля по ним. Подстановка id напрямую ничего не меняет

Comment: Нужно добавить к user_id приставку "user_".$author_id ); и будет работать

Comment: Действительно) Огромное спасибо)